# How can I increase trackpad sensitivity?

Tags: touchpad

I am new to Linux and downloaded Ubuntu 20.04. My trackpad isn't working properly. I have to press down somewhat to use the trackpad. That is the only time it works. How do I increase the sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) and touchpad extensions that can be added through it.

If you don't mind getting along the Terminal, the answer provided to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973090/how-to-configure-touchpad-tap-sensitivity) could also help.